# link cursor changed to hand for all browsers: how to change back

Tags: mouse, browser, mate-desktop

```
 mate-desktop 1.26.1-1
 6.3.9-arch1-1`

 Mozilla Firefox 114.0.2
 Brave Browser 114.1.52.129 
 Chromium 114.0.5735.198 Arch Linux
```

When hovering mouse over link on web page the cursor switches to hand. How do I change that back to normal.

In the MATE appearances I have tried a number of themes and none offer any pointer other than default.

ChatGPT totally useless on this question.

Comment: Were you adjusting themes before this happened? Some desktop customization tools have layers of adjustments that overlap, such as themes, appearance, icons, etc. Sometimes one layer overrides another in not entirely predictable ways unless you know what they're doing.